# Cordova Filetransfer a pdf file from app to device | Using Monaca IDE

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, monaca

Alright so I've downloaded the plugin from the Monaca/Cordova plugin repository. Then I added the javascript from the FileTransfer plugin site for the download and replaced the encodeURI with the file path.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download

```
<script>
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://www.ulc.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/King-James-Bible-KJV-Bible-PDF.pdf");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

I'm trying to call it with an onclick function using html..

```
<button onclick="FileTransfer()">Download</button>
```

It doesn't work though, how can I get the file to download onclick to their device?

Answer (score 0):

First, your uri not download automacally.

Try:

`var pdfFileUrl = "https://wogopezup2016.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/giao-an-dien-tu-tieu-hoc.pdf";`

Second, please define **"fileURL"** parameter.

Try:

```
'/storage/emulated/0/path/to/';  // For Android
                        cordova.file.documentsDirectory; // For ios
```